# Executing a shell in CakePHP

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, console, cakephp-2.0

I am executing a shell on a Fedora 8 32 bit server with php 5.2.6 and Cakephp 2. I am getting these errors :

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  tag in path/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleOutput.php on line 202
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  emergency in path/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleOutput.php on line 217
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  alert in path/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleOutput.php on line 217
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  critical in path/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleOutput.php on line 217
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  error in path/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleOutput.php on line 217
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  warning in path/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleOutput.php on line 217
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  info in path/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleOutput.php on line 217
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  debug in path/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleOutput.php on line 217
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  success in path/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleOutput.php on line 217
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  comment in path/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleOutput.php on line 217
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  question in path/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleOutput.php on line 217
```

and so on.

This works fine when I try it locally. Any idea ?

Comment: If I read a book and try to open page 123456, I cannot find it! Any ideas? In other words; please show your code

Comment: If i go to the path cake is installed and just type "cake", all those errors appears. There is no code whatsoever that I have modify from Cake.

Comment: You should be launching it with `./Console/cake` from the `app` directory.

Comment: That is actually what I did

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you use an old PHP version. CakePHP 2 requires at least PHP 5.2.8, see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#requirements